# What is the purpose of the .twilio-functions file in the Twilio Functions?

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I used `twilio serverless:init` to generate a Twilio service locally and then later deployed it to Twilio. At some point I noticed a file named `.twilio-functions` present in the root of the project. It's contents looked like this:

```
{
        "projects": {
                "<redacted>": {
                        "serviceSid": "<redacted>",
                        "latestBuild": "<redacted>"
                }
        },
        "serviceSid": "<redacted>",
        "latestBuild": "<redacted>"
}
```

**What is the purpose of this file? Do I need to keep it? If so, should it be versioned?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.twilio-functions` is created when you call `twilio serverless:deploy` . It basically just keeps a log of the latest build and service SIDs.

You can delete it if you want, since I don't think it's used anywhere. But I would just leave it, since it doesn't hurt and it will keep reappearing every time you deploy.

You don't need to store it in version control, since it's an output of the deploy process, like a log. It might already be ignored in the auto-generated `.gitignore` file. If it's not there, you can add it as was done in these GitHub [repos](https://github.com/search?q=.twilio-functions%20in%3Afile%20filename%3A.gitignore).

#### References

If you want to know where this config file is created:

- The [create-twilio-function](https://github.com/twilio-labs/create-twilio-function) CLI tool targets the deploy script in [create-files.js](https://github.com/twilio-labs/create-twilio-function/blob/7dcd686758e90ec2c6e9ef53de2f48d486f92271/src/create-twilio-function/create-files.js#L36)
- deploy.ts is implemented in twilio [serverless-toolkit](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit)
- deploy.ts [calls](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/blob/90a3e63921ce886dd8aa578c7ad528d0626681a5/packages/twilio-run/src/commands/deploy.ts#L117-L124) the method [saveLatestDeploymentData](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/blob/90a3e63921ce886dd8aa578c7ad528d0626681a5/packages/twilio-run/src/serverless-api/utils.ts#L33-L54), which creates the config data structure